# SSIS Script Component JSON DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: json, ssis, script-component

Edit - 5/8 Json sample:

```
{
"data": [
  {
"evidenceId": "9999A999-9D99-4411-8819-DD55D9DDD55D",
"status": "Active",
"title": "Video 2017-04-30 2354",
"idExternal": null,
"description": null,
"dateUploaded": "2017-05-01T01:33:10.522-06:00",
"dateModified": "2017-05-01T01:33:10.970-06:00",
"dateRecordStart": "2017-04-30T23:54:38.000-06:00",
"dateRecordEnd": "2017-04-30T23:59:10.000-06:00",
"dateDeleted": "2017-08-28T23:54:38.000-06:00",
"evidenceType": "Video",
"flag": "N",
"contentType": "mp4",
"sizeMb": 40.36958312988281,
"durationSeconds": "272.76",
"ownerFirstName": "D B",
"ownerLastName": "ITE",
"ownerBadgeId": "9999",
"ownerRole": "Officer/PSA's",
"ownerGroups": [],
"updatedByFirstName": "",
"updatedByLastName": "",
"updatedByBadgeId": "",
"updatedByRole": "",
"deletedByFirstName": "",
"deletedByLastName": "",
"deletedByBadgeId": "",
"deletedByRole": "",
"uploadedByFirstName": "D B",
"uploadedByLastName": "ITE",
"uploadedByBadgeId": "9999",
"uploadedByRole": "Officer/PSA's",
"gps": {
"latitude": null,
"longitude": null
},
"deviceId": "8888A888-8D88-4411-8819-DD55D9DDD66E",
"notes": [],
"categories": [
  "120 Day Deletion"
],
"tags": [],
"cases": [],
"viewCount": 0,
"lastViewedOn": null,
"isReassigned": false,
"authenticatedShareCount": 0,
"deletionType": "",
"checksum": "{sha2}33aa3724c8b3bb647a27fb3a895867c8214508b0cdba6e66882095f22b29f23d",
"downloadCount": 0
},
  {
"evidenceId": "7777A777-9E99-4411-8819-EE55E9EEE55E",
"status": "Active",
"title": "Video 2017-04-30 2354",
"idExternal": null,
"description": null,
"dateUploaded": "2017-05-02T01:02:08.180-06:00",
"dateModified": "2017-05-02T01:02:08.530-06:00",
"dateRecordStart": "2017-04-30T23:54:04.000-06:00",
"dateRecordEnd": "2017-05-01T00:01:53.000-06:00",
"dateDeleted": "2017-08-28T23:54:04.000-06:00",
"evidenceType": "Video",
"flag": "N",
"contentType": "mp4",
"sizeMb": 68.5533447265625,
"durationSeconds": "469.03",
"ownerFirstName": "C S",
"ownerLastName": "NARRO",
"ownerBadgeId": "5555",
"ownerRole": "Officer/PSA's",
"ownerGroups": [],
"updatedByFirstName": "",
"updatedByLastName": "",
"updatedByBadgeId": "",
"updatedByRole": "",
"deletedByFirstName": "",
"deletedByLastName": "",
"deletedByBadgeId": "",
"deletedByRole": "",
"uploadedByFirstName": "C S",
"uploadedByLastName": "NARRO",
"uploadedByBadgeId": "5555",
"uploadedByRole": "Officer/PSA's",
"gps": {
"latitude": null,
"longitude": null
},
"deviceId": "2F87080C-8AB2-4BB5-A3F4-E8E51D648B79",
"notes": [],
"categories": [
  "120 Day Deletion"
],
"tags": [],
"cases": [],
"viewCount": 0,
"lastViewedOn": null,
"isReassigned": false,
"authenticatedShareCount": 0,
"deletionType": "",
"checksum": "{sha2}47256fe19712a852198a5ac45aef949f4b1ad1011dddc16b6674add514a2d614",
"downloadCount": 0
}
],
}
```

**Edit - 5/5 Additional Information:**

Here is my updated code for my actual project.  I can now see that I am getting data if I restrict the parameters to a single result.  but when I increase the results I can't get the foreach to work correctly.  I have had to hardcode the array values.  I appreciate any help in getting this working!!

```
#region Class



[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent

{


    #region Methods



    /// <summary>Outputs records to the output buffer</summary>

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()

    {


        //Set Webservice URL

        string wUrl = "https://api.evidence.com/api/v1/agencies/{partnerId}/reports/data?reportType=EvidenceCreated&fromDate=2017-04-01&toDate=2017-04-30&pageSize=5&pageOffset=0";



        try

        {



            //Call getWebServiceResult to return our Article attributes

            RootObject outPutResponse = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);


            //If we get data back

            if (outPutResponse != null)

            {

                foreach (Datum ar in outPutResponse.data)

              //  {

                    //Output main attributes of Article

                    EvidenceBuffer.AddRow();

                    EvidenceBuffer.evidenceId = outPutResponse.data[0].evidenceId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.status = outPutResponse.data[0].status;

                    EvidenceBuffer.title = outPutResponse.data[0].title;

                    EvidenceBuffer.idExternal = outPutResponse.data[0].idExternal;

                    EvidenceBuffer.description = outPutResponse.data[0].description;

                    EvidenceBuffer.dateUploaded = outPutResponse.data[0].dateUploaded;

                    EvidenceBuffer.dateModified = outPutResponse.data[0].dateModified;

                    EvidenceBuffer.dateRecordStart = outPutResponse.data[0].dateRecordStart;

                    EvidenceBuffer.dateRecordEnd = outPutResponse.data[0].dateRecordEnd;

                    EvidenceBuffer.dateDeleted = outPutResponse.data[0].dateDeleted;

                    EvidenceBuffer.evidenceType = outPutResponse.data[0].evidenceType;

                    EvidenceBuffer.flag = outPutResponse.data[0].flag;

                    EvidenceBuffer.contentType = outPutResponse.data[0].contentType;

                    EvidenceBuffer.sizeMb = outPutResponse.data[0].sizeMb;

                    EvidenceBuffer.durationSeconds = outPutResponse.data[0].durationSeconds;

                    EvidenceBuffer.ownerFirstName = outPutResponse.data[0].ownerFirstName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.ownerLastName = outPutResponse.data[0].ownerLastName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.ownerBadgeId = outPutResponse.data[0].ownerBadgeId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.ownerRole = outPutResponse.data[0].ownerRole;

                    EvidenceBuffer.ownerGroups = outPutResponse.data[0].ownerGroups;

                    EvidenceBuffer.updatedByFirstName = outPutResponse.data[0].updatedByFirstName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.updatedByLastName = outPutResponse.data[0].updatedByLastName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.updatedByBadgeId = outPutResponse.data[0].updatedByBadgeId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.updatedByRole = outPutResponse.data[0].updatedByRole;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deletedByFirstName = outPutResponse.data[0].deletedByFirstName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deletedByLastName = outPutResponse.data[0].deletedByLastName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deletedByBadgeId = outPutResponse.data[0].deletedByBadgeId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deletedByRole = outPutResponse.data[0].deletedByRole;

                    EvidenceBuffer.uploadedByFirstName = outPutResponse.data[0].uploadedByFirstName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.uploadedByLastName = outPutResponse.data[0].uploadedByLastName;

                    EvidenceBuffer.uploadedByBadgeId = outPutResponse.data[0].uploadedByBadgeId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.uploadedByRole = outPutResponse.data[0].uploadedByRole;

                    EvidenceBuffer.gpslat = null;

                    EvidenceBuffer.gpslong = null;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deviceId = outPutResponse.data[0].deviceId;

                    EvidenceBuffer.notes = outPutResponse.data[0].notes[0];

                    EvidenceBuffer.categories = outPutResponse.data[0].categories[0];


                    EvidenceBuffer.tags = outPutResponse.data[0].tags[0];

                    EvidenceBuffer.cases = outPutResponse.data[0].cases[0];

                    EvidenceBuffer.viewCount = outPutResponse.data[0].viewCount;

                    EvidenceBuffer.lastViewedOn = outPutResponse.data[0].lastViewedOn;

                    EvidenceBuffer.isReassigned = outPutResponse.data[0].isReassigned;

                    EvidenceBuffer.authenicatedShareCount = outPutResponse.data[0].authenticatedShareCount;

                    EvidenceBuffer.deletionType = outPutResponse.data[0].deletionType;

                    EvidenceBuffer.checksum = outPutResponse.data[0].checksum;

                    EvidenceBuffer.downloadCount = outPutResponse.data[0].downloadCount;


                //}

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)

        {

            FailComponent(e.ToString());

        }


    }


    /// <summary>

    /// Method to return our list articles

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="wUrl">The web service URL to call</param>

    /// <returns>An object that contains a list of Articles</returns>



    private RootObject GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)

    {



        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);

        httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer SecretCode");

        httpWReq.Method = "GET";

        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();


        RootObject jsonResponse = null;


        try

        {

            //Get the stream of JSON

            Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();




            //Deserialize the JSON stream

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))

            {



                //Deserialize our JSON

                DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

                jsonResponse = (RootObject)sr.ReadObject(responseStream);

            }




        }

        //Output JSON parsing error

        catch (Exception e)

        {

            FailComponent(e.ToString());

        }

        return jsonResponse;


    }


    /// <summary>

    /// Outputs error message

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="errorMsg">Full error text</param>

    private void FailComponent(string errorMsg)

    {

        bool fail = false;

        IDTSComponentMetaData100 compMetadata = this.ComponentMetaData;

        compMetadata.FireError(1, "Error Getting Data From Webservice!", errorMsg, "", 0, out fail);


    }

    #endregion

}

#endregion


#region JSON Classes

//Class to hold attributes of the Article

[DataContract]

public class Gps
{
    [DataMember(Name = "latitude")]
    public object latitude { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "longitude")]
    public object longitude { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    [DataMember(Name = "evidenceId")]
    public string evidenceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "idExternal")]
    public string idExternal { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateUploaded")]
    public string dateUploaded { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateModified")]
    public string dateModified { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateRecordStart")]
    public string dateRecordStart { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateRecordEnd")]
    public string dateRecordEnd { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "dateDeleted")]
    public string dateDeleted { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "evidenceType")]
    public string evidenceType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "flag")]
    public string flag { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "contentType")]
    public string contentType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "sizeMb")]
    public float sizeMb { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "durationSeconds")]
    public float durationSeconds { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ownerFirstName")]
    public string ownerFirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ownerLastName")]
    public string ownerLastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ownerBadgeId")]
    public string ownerBadgeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ownerRole")]
    public string ownerRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "ownerGroups")]
    public string ownerGroups { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "updatedByFirstName")]
    public string updatedByFirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "updatedByLastName")]
    public string updatedByLastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "updatedByBadgeId")]
    public string updatedByBadgeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "updatedByRole")]
    public string updatedByRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deletedByFirstName")]
    public string deletedByFirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deletedByLastName")]
    public string deletedByLastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deletedByBadgeId")]
    public string deletedByBadgeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deletedByRole")]
    public string deletedByRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "uploadedByFirstName")]
    public string uploadedByFirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "uploadedByLastName")]
    public string uploadedByLastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "uploadedByBadgeId")]
    public string uploadedByBadgeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "uploadedByRole")]
    public string uploadedByRole { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "gps")]
    public Gps gps { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deviceId")]
    public string deviceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "notes")]
    public List<string> notes { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "categories")]
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "tags")]
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "cases")]
    public List<string> cases { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "viewCount")]
    public int viewCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "lastViewedOn")]
    public string lastViewedOn { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isReassigned")]
    public bool isReassigned { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "authenticatedShareCount")]
    public int authenticatedShareCount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "deletionType")]
    public string deletionType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "checksum")]
    public string checksum { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "downloadCount")]
    public int downloadCount { get; set; }
}


//Root object that contains a List of data

[DataContract]


public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

#endregion
```

---

Original post:

I am using this sample to try and get an SSIS package to consume from an API.  I was unable to get my JSON to work (and the API used in the sample has moved so I was unable to get it to work "as is") so I decided to try with something easy.

https://dennysjymbo.blogspot.com/2014/03/utilizing-net-40-datacontractjsonserial.html?showComment=1493916532059#c208608008820233205

I am trying to create a simple SSIS package to consume this information from  https://swapi.co/api/people/1

Here is my script:

```
#region Namespaces

using System;

using System.Data;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

using System.Net;

using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

using System.IO;

using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

using System.Runtime.Serialization;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Text;

#endregion


#region Class



[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]

public class ScriptMain : UserComponent

{


    #region Methods



    /// <summary>Outputs records to the output buffer</summary>

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()

    {


        //Set Webservice URL

        //string wUrl = "https://api.evidence.com/api/v1/agencies/3DCB15D3-3770-4DC4-8D22-4FB1FA8619A5/reports/data?reportType=EvidenceCreated&fromDate=2017-04-01&toDate=2017-04-30&pageSize=5&pageOffset=0";
        string wUrl = "http://swapi.co/api/people/1";


        try

        {



            //Call getWebServiceResult to return our Article attributes

            RootObject outPutResponse = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);


            //If we get data back

            if (outPutResponse != null)

            {

                foreach (People ar in outPutResponse.people)

                {

                    //Output main attributes of Article

                    PeopleBuffer.AddRow();

                    PeopleBuffer.name = ar.name;

                    PeopleBuffer.height = ar.height;

                    PeopleBuffer.mass = ar.mass;

                    PeopleBuffer.haircolor = ar.hair_color;

                    PeopleBuffer.skincolor = ar.skin_color;

                    PeopleBuffer.eyecolor = ar.eye_color;

                    PeopleBuffer.birthyear = ar.birth_year;

                    PeopleBuffer.gender = ar.gender;

                    PeopleBuffer.homeworld = ar.homeworld;

                    PeopleBuffer.films = ar.films[0];

                    PeopleBuffer.species = ar.species[0];

                    PeopleBuffer.vehicles = ar.vehicles[0];

                    PeopleBuffer.starships = ar.starships[0];

                    PeopleBuffer.created = ar.created;

                    PeopleBuffer.edited = ar.edited;

                    PeopleBuffer.url = ar.url;

                    }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)

        {

            FailComponent(e.ToString());

        }


    }


    /// <summary>

    /// Method to return our list articles

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="wUrl">The web service URL to call</param>

    /// <returns>An object that contains a list of Articles</returns>



    private RootObject GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)

    {



        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);

        //httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer HxS35IIN36b9EW64L+GG3xYhoz66bNaD8hsckfQGPdk=");

        httpWReq.Method = "GET";

        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";

        HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();


        RootObject jsonResponse = null;


        try

        {

            //Get the stream of JSON

            Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();




            //Deserialize the JSON stream

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))

            {



                //Deserialize our JSON

                DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RootObject));

                jsonResponse = (RootObject)sr.ReadObject(responseStream);

            }




        }

        //Output JSON parsing error

        catch (Exception e)

        {

            FailComponent(e.ToString());

        }

        return jsonResponse;


    }


    /// <summary>

    /// Outputs error message

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="errorMsg">Full error text</param>

    private void FailComponent(string errorMsg)

    {

        bool fail = false;

        IDTSComponentMetaData100 compMetadata = this.ComponentMetaData;

        compMetadata.FireError(1, "Error Getting Data From Webservice!", errorMsg, "", 0, out fail);


    }

    #endregion

}

#endregion


#region JSON Classes

//Class to hold attributes of the Article

[DataContract]


public class People
{
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "height")]
    public string height { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "mass")]
    public string mass { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "hair_color")]
    public string hair_color { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "skin_color")]
    public string skin_color { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "eye_color")]
    public string eye_color { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "birth_year")]
    public string birth_year { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "gender")]
    public string gender { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "homeworld")]
    public string homeworld { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "films")]
    public List<string> films { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "species")]
    public List<string> species { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "vehicles")]
    public List<string> vehicles { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "starships")]
    public List<string> starships { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "created")]
    public DateTime created { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "edited")]
    public DateTime edited { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string url { get; set; }
}

//Root object that contains a List of Articles

[DataContract]

public class RootObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "people")]

    public List<People> people { get; set; }
}


#endregion
```

this is the line that is not working correctly:

```
jsonResponse = (RootObject)sr.ReadObject(responseStream);
```

In the image you can see that it added a people object but none of the data is there.

[image]

I would appreciate any help in figuring out what I need to modify in order to get the data in the response object.

Thanks!

Edit:
The actual error message that the ssis package gives is:

```
Error: 0x1 at Data Flow Task, Error Getting Data From Webservice!: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at ScriptMain.CreateNewOutputRows() in c:\Users\E37026\AppData\Local\Temp\Vsta\747a4fee6a1f4610a91610400e06a1ac\main.cs:line 81
```

Comment: Any way you can provide a de-identified json sample?

Comment: @jymbo - here is the JSON sample!  Thank you!

Comment: I got it to work!  I needed to change the foreach to a for with an index value since the RootObject is a list not a collection!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things here. First your url should be http://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json. Second is that you are not getting an array of people back, so you need to change this to a single object. Third the serializer doesn't like the datetime values, I changed them to strings and it worked. You can work on changing this in the staging area or in a derived column transform. Here is the code:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
#endregion

#region Class
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
 {

#region Methods



/// <summary>Outputs records to the output buffer</summary>

public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{


    //Set Webservice URL

    //string wUrl = "https://api.evidence.com/api/v1/agencies/3DCB15D3-3770-4DC4-8D22-4FB1FA8619A5/reports/data?reportType=EvidenceCreated&fromDate=2017-04-01&toDate=2017-04-30&pageSize=5&pageOffset=0";
    string wUrl = "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/?format=json";


    try
    {



        //Call getWebServiceResult to return our Article attributes

        People outPutResponse = GetWebServiceResult(wUrl);


        //If we get data back

        if (outPutResponse != null)
        {



                //Output main attributes of Article

                PeopleBuffer.AddRow();

                PeopleBuffer.name = outPutResponse.name;

                PeopleBuffer.height = outPutResponse.height;

                PeopleBuffer.mass = outPutResponse.mass;

                PeopleBuffer.haircolor = outPutResponse.hair_color;

                PeopleBuffer.skincolor = outPutResponse.skin_color;

                PeopleBuffer.eyecolor = outPutResponse.eye_color;

                PeopleBuffer.birthyear = outPutResponse.birth_year;

                PeopleBuffer.gender = outPutResponse.gender;

                PeopleBuffer.homeworld = outPutResponse.homeworld;

                PeopleBuffer.films = outPutResponse.films[0];

                PeopleBuffer.species = outPutResponse.species[0];

                PeopleBuffer.vehicles = outPutResponse.vehicles[0];

                PeopleBuffer.starships = outPutResponse.starships[0];

                PeopleBuffer.created = outPutResponse.created;

                PeopleBuffer.edited = outPutResponse.edited;

                PeopleBuffer.url = outPutResponse.url;

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        FailComponent(e.ToString());

    }


}


/// <summary>

/// Method to return our list articles

/// </summary>

/// <param name="wUrl">The web service URL to call</param>

/// <returns>An object that contains a list of Articles</returns>



private People GetWebServiceResult(string wUrl)
{



    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);

    //httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer HxS35IIN36b9EW64L+GG3xYhoz66bNaD8hsckfQGPdk=");

    httpWReq.Method = "GET";

    httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";

    HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();


    People jsonResponse = null;


    try
    {

        //Get the stream of JSON

        Stream responseStream = httpWResp.GetResponseStream();




        //Deserialize the JSON stream

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {



            //Deserialize our JSON

            DataContractJsonSerializer sr = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(People));

            jsonResponse = (People)sr.ReadObject(responseStream);

        }




    }

    //Output JSON parsing error

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        FailComponent(e.ToString());

    }

    return jsonResponse;


}


/// <summary>

/// Outputs error message

/// </summary>

/// <param name="errorMsg">Full error text</param>

private void FailComponent(string errorMsg)
{

    bool fail = false;

    IDTSComponentMetaData100 compMetadata = this.ComponentMetaData;

    compMetadata.FireError(1, "Error Getting Data From Webservice!", errorMsg, "", 0, out fail);


  }

 #endregion

}

#endregion


 #region JSON Classes

 //Class to hold attributes of the Article

[DataContract]
 public class People
{
[DataMember(Name = "name")]
public string name { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "height")]
public string height { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "mass")]
public string mass { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "hair_color")]
public string hair_color { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "skin_color")]
public string skin_color { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "eye_color")]
public string eye_color { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "birth_year")]
public string birth_year { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "gender")]
public string gender { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "homeworld")]
public string homeworld { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "films")]
public List<string> films { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "species")]
public List<string> species { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "vehicles")]
public List<string> vehicles { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "starships")]
public List<string> starships { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "created")]
public string created { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "edited")]
public string edited { get; set; }

[DataMember(Name = "url")]
public string url { get; set; }
}



#endregion
```

Comment: great thank you so much - that worked!  However this was just my practice example to try and get something to work!  My final product will be returning multiple records.  I will try and make the required changes in order to get that working and post back if I have any other questions.